# Earlier ActionFilterAttribute execution in base controller - MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, inheritance, actionfilterattribute

I have the following setup. When an action is executed in GuestDetailsController, how can I have[LoadThemeInfo] run prior to [RequireCheckoutAvailability] **without having to specify orders on the child controller's attributes?**  The filters all use OnActionExecuting.

```
[LoadThemeInfo(Order=1)]
public class MgControllerBase : Controller
{

}

[RequireCheckoutAvailability(Order=2)]
public class GuestDetailsController : MgControllerBase
{

}
```

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute.order.aspx): *The Order property takes an integer value that must be 0 (the default) or greater, with one exception. Omitting the Order property gives the filter an order value of -1, which indicates an unspecified order. Any action filter in a scope whose Order property is set to -1 will be executed in an undetermined order, but before the filters that have a specified order.*

I would prefer the unspecifieds execute after those with a specified order in this case. Is there another way to do what I am trying to achieve? Maybe move load theme info code out of the attribute and somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the order in the constructor of the attribute.  In order to keep the execution orders in one place and keep it easy to maintain as new attributes get added, create an `enum` such as:

```
 public enum CustomActionFilterOrder{
     LoadThemeInfo = 1,
     RequireCheckoutAvailability = 2,
 }
```

and the Attribute constructor will look like

```
public RequireCheckoutAvailability(){
    this.Order = (int)CustomActionFilterOrder.RequireCheckoutAvailability;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a nice way to arrange it, I was trying to avoid a maintenaince nightmare after all...

Answer (score 0):

Taking the ActionFilterAttribute off the base controller and calling it from an overridden OnActionExecuting makes it execute earlier than attributes on child controllers.

```
public class MgControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var filter = new LoadThemeInfoFilter(DependencyLookup.Resolve<IBrandContext>());
        filter.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

[RequireCheckoutAvailability]
public class GuestDetailsController : MgControllerBase
{

}
```